# To delete the last character with regex

Tags: regex, asp-classic, character

```vbs
regex.Pattern = "(.*?),$"
```

**Examle Text:**

> Lorem ipsum,lorem,ipsum,lorem,

**I want (True)**

> Lorem ipsum,lorem,ipsum,lorem

the last character `,` (comma) to be deleted
I'm using Classic ASP.

```vbs
kelime = "Lorem ipsum,lorem,ipsum,lorem,"   
Dim regex
Set regex = New RegExp
regex.IgnoreCase = True
regex.Pattern = "(.*?),$"
Set colMatches = regex.Execute(kelime)
If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
    strTitle = colMatches(0).Value
    'strTitle.Remove(strTitle.Length - 1)
Else
    strTitle = ""
End If
response.write strTitle
```

Comment: regex.Pattern = "(.*?)," negative. because result : Lorem ipsum,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kelime=left(kelime,len(kelime)-1)

Comment: strTitle.Remove(strTitle.Length - 1) bunu regex içinde mi kullanmam gerekiyor huseyin. in regex did not work

Comment: This looks more like ASP.NET than Classic ASP.

Comment: longtext field does not work. varchar worked. But I have to use my longtext

Comment: why especially longtext

Comment: because there are areas in more than 500 characters.